# Plotly express stacked bar chart for reflecting hover_data correctly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python, stacked-bar-chart

I have a simple data frame called `wide_df`, and its contents are as follows:

[image: Contents of the dataframe]

I am trying to plot it, using plotly express as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(wide_df, 
    x=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], 
    y="nation", 
    title="Reasons for Success",  orientation='h' , 
    color_discrete_map={'gold':'green', 'silver':'grey', 'bronze':'red'}, 
    hover_data=['gold reasons', 'silver reasons', 'bronze reasons'])
fig.show()
```

The resulting px graph is as shown below:
[image: Plotly stacked bar with color and hover data]

While all the other things seems to be working, I am unable to get the hover_data right. When I hover it over, say Canada's bronze bar, It should show only `bronze reasons=sleep, rest`. Whereas it shows all reasons: `gold reasons=good food, life style, silver reasons=training, concentration, bronze reasons=sleep, rest`. Can anyone help me sort out this issue? Online docs and APIs are not much decipherable. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is, because your dataframe is in wide format, you have to specify the 3 columns `['gold reasons', 'silver reasons', 'bronze reasons']` as `hover_data`, but Plotly cannot know that each column has also one corresponding column `["gold", "silver", "bronze"]`, it just creates 3 traces for each medal column (as specified by `x`) and adds the `hover_data` (all 3 reasons) to each trace.

When using `hover_data`, Plotly actually adds those data as [`customdata`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/bar/#bar-customdata) under the hood and reuse them in [`hovertemplate`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/bar/#bar-hovertemplate). You can do this manually, specifying for each trace its corresponding reason column and only that column :

```py
fig = px.bar(wide_df,
    x=["gold", "silver", "bronze"],
    y="nation",
    title="Reasons for Success",
    orientation='h',
    color_discrete_map={'gold':'green', 'silver':'grey', 'bronze':'red'}
    )

for i, trace in enumerate(fig.data):
    column = f'{trace.name} reasons'
    fig.data[i]['customdata'] = wide_df[column]
    fig.data[i]['hovertemplate'] += f'<br>{column}=' + '%{customdata}'
```

---

You could also unpivot the dataframe from wide to long format (ie. with columns `nation, medal, count, reason`), then you would just do :

```py
fig = px.bar(long_df,
    x="count",
    y="nation",
    color="medal",
    title="Reasons for Success",
    orientation='h' ,
    color_discrete_map={'gold':'green', 'silver':'grey', 'bronze':'red'},
    hover_data="reason"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a ton EricLavault,  I could manage with the wide format, regards